# Data type mismatch in criteria expression excel C#

Tags: c#

I got some problem when I run my code. It says

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression

in

```
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
```

I don't know what the mistake is. Can anyone help me ?

```
private void JumlahLembar()
{
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in JadwalisiGV.Rows)
    {
        int lim30den50tot;

        if (!row.IsNewRow)
        {
            OleDbConnection kon = new OleDbConnection(koneksi);
            OleDbCommand command = kon.CreateCommand();

            kon.Open();
            command.CommandText = "select * from [StokLembar$] where [Limit] = '" + row.Cells["Limit"].Value + "'";
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                int den50 = int.Parse(reader["Lembar Denom 50"].ToString());
                int den100 = int.Parse(reader["Lembar Denom 100"].ToString());

                if (row.Cells["Limit"].Value.ToString() == "30")
                {
                    lim30++;
                    lim30den50tot = lim30 * lim30 * 2 * 1000000 * den50 * 50000;
                    TotalDen50Box.Text = lim30den50tot.ToString();

                }
            }

            kon.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your query, `command.CommandText = "select * from [StokLembar$] where [Limit] = '" + row.Cells["Limit"].Value + "'";`, what is the data type of [Limit] in database? row.Cells["Limit"].Value is going to return an `object`. You might need to cast it to and `int` or `string` depending on the data type of [Limit] in database

Comment: Data type of [Limit] is General. The data in [Limit] is integer actually. By the way I am using Excel to be my database

Comment: if Limit contain numbers you better change the column data type as number or if that column contain text content you better change the excel column data type as text. if the column data type text your code is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set `Limit` as text column, most probably it may be number. try below without quotes

```
command.CommandText = "select * from [StokLembar$] where [Limit] = " + row.Cells["Limit"].Value`
```

You better use parameters instead of concatenating SQL statement to avoid sql injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Go for a parameter based query running under a `using` as:

```
  using (OleDbCommand command = conn.CreateCommand())
  {
       // create command with placeholders
       cmd.CommandText = 
          "SELECT * FROM [StokLembar$] WHERE [Limit] = @limit ";

       // add named parameters
       command.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
       {
           new OleDbParameter("@limit", row.Cells["Limit"].Value)
       });

       // execute
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
```

<del>I'm assuming [Limit] is a string type in the database. Your mileage may vary.</del>
As pointed out by @Patrick-Hofman, the database can now figure out on its own.

Comment: Remove `.ToString()` and let the database find out the correct type.